# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de un formulario mediante javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy creando una página web y quiero programar una sección de comentarios, que contenga la fecha y la hora en que el usuario comentó. Por ser primerizo en el tema, estoy haciendo un mal uso del lenguaje JavaScript para ese caso. Deseo que una vez que los datos se envíen a MYSQL, se devuelvan a la página.

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Formulario</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {              
        $(document).on('submit', '#mi_formulario', function() {   
            //Obtenemos datos.          
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({            
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'insertar.php',
                data : data,
                success :  function(data) {                 
                    $("#resultado-mi-formulario").html(data).fadeIn();
                },
                complete: function(){
                   setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#resultado-mi-formulario").fadeOut();
                   }, 15000);    
                }
            });         
            return false;           
        });        
    });//End document

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form id="mi_formulario" action= "insertar.php" method="POST">
  <Label for="nombre">Nombre:</Label>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email"  required=""placeholder="Escribe tu email..."> <br><br>
  <input type="password" name="clave" required="" placeholder="Escribe tu clave..."><br><br>
  <textarea type="comentario" name="comentario" cols="90px" rows="8" required="" placeholder="Escriba aquí su comentario..."></textarea><br><br>
  </form>
  <div id="resultado-mi-formulario></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Este es mi código PHP:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try { 
    echo "datos enviados correctamente";
    $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
    $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
    $sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
    $sql->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

eliminar.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Boton eliminar.
 $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     //Variable con el valor del boton.
     var id = $(this).attr('data-id');   

      //Comprobar alerta ID en pantalla.
     //alert(id);

     //Ajax.
     $.post('eliminar.php', {
        Id:id
     },function(supr) {
        if (supr=='0') {          
           location.href="formulario2.html";
        }
     }); 
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: No se como usarlo. ¿Me podrías explicar?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104074/como-usar-ajax-en-un-formulario

Answer (score 2):

Podrías serializar el formulario y mandarlo al servidor utilizando ajax, podría ser algo así:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url a la que vas a mandar los datos",
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(res){
        //Código a ejecutar si la petición se ejecutó correctamente
    },
    error: function(){
        //Código a ejecutar si hubo un error al ejecutar la petición
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando JQuery Puedes serializar la forma para enviar un arreglo de objetos al backend

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var Datos = $( this ).serializeArray()
  var ArrayJSON = JSON.stringify(Datos)
  //Aqui usar el Ajax de la respuesta anterior solo en data mandar como parametro ArrayJson
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Saludos

Comment: Utilice el AJAX, y funciona perfectamente, pero en ves de mostrar el nombre de la persona autora del comentario, solo aparece "Datos enviados correctamente". Editando la pregunta, ¿me seguirían explicando?

Comment: Ademas, los campos del formulario siguen teniendo la información introducida. No se actualiza al momento del envío.

Comment: Como estas enviando los datos en JSON en PHP debes dar decode a la variable enviada para obtener los datos, por ejemplo

$obj = json_decode($_POST["NombreVariable"]);

y ya de la variable $obj obtienes los datos, ejemplo:

$nombre = $obj->nombre;

Comment: ¿Lo coloco en el archivo de PHP? Chequea el código recién que coloque en la pregunta.

Comment: Justo deje una imagen para una mejor visualización del problema.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante Ajax.

Te muestro aquí un ejemplo usando Ajax con jQuery:

#### HTML/JAVASCRIPT

Primero, debes incluir la biblioteca jQuery en el encabezado, si ya la tienes omite este paso. Observa que estoy poniendo la última versión de jQuery. si tienes una muy vieja como las versiones `1` o `2`, aprovecha y actualiza a la más nueva que es la versión 3.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

En el mismo `head` puedes poner este código, que será la petición Ajax, siempre debajo del script que incluye la librería:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#comentar' ).click(function(e) 
    {

        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $('#f_coment');
        var data=frm.serialize();
        var textOuput="";
        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url:      frm.attr('action'),    //Lo toma del form
                method:   frm.attr('method'),   //Lo toma del form
                data:     data,
                dataType: 'html' 
            });
    
            request.done(function( response ) 
            {
                console.log(response); //prueba
                textOutput=response;
    
            });
    
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
            {
                alert( 'Error en la petición: ' + textStatus );
                textOutput="error: "+textStatus;
            });
    
            request.always(function() {
                $('#info').text(textOutput);
            });
        });    
});
```

Luego, tu formulario, tal cual, solamente hemos cambiado la etiqueta `name` del mismo por `id` para poder alcanzarlo más fácilmente en Javascript:

```
<form id="f_coment" action= "insertar.php" method="POST">
<Label for="nombre">Nombre:</Label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" required=""placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."><br>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email"  required=""placeholder="Escribe tu email..."> <br>
<label for="clave">Clave:</label>
<input type="password" name="clave" required="" placeholder="Escribe tu clave..."><br>
<label for="comentario">Comentario:</label>
<textarea type="comentario" name="comentario" cols="90px" rows="8" required="" placeholder="Escriba aquí su comentario..."></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="comentar" id="comentar">
```

Puedes agregar un contenedor, que usaremos para mostrar las respuestas que vengan del servidor. El mismo estará vacío y se actualizará cuando ocurra la petición:

```
<div id="info"><div>
```

---

#### PHP

La petición en el servidor la puedes manejar así:

```
<?php
 
    error_reporting(0);
    $nombre    = ( empty($_POST['nombre']) )     ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
    $email     = ( empty($_POST['email']) )      ? NULL : $_POST['email'];
    $clave     = ( empty($_POST['clave']) )      ? NULL : $_POST['clave'];
    $comentario= ( empty($_POST['comentario']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['comentario'];
    
    if ($nombre && $email && $clave && $comentario){
        $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
        try { 
            $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
            $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
            $sql->bindParam(':email',$email);
            $sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
            $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$comentario);
            $sql->execute();
            $msgOut="Se insertaron ".$sql->rowCount()." filas";
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            $msgOut="Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $msgOut="Faltan datos en el POST";
    }
    echo $msgOut;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="formulario1">
     <input type="text" name="comentario">
     <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

## javascript - jquery

```
var frm=document.querySelector("#formulario1")
//validas que exista el elemento form con el id #formulario
if(frm){
  //agregamos el evento submit al frm
  frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    //prevenimos la acción por defecto de submit - evita recarga de la pagina
   e.preventDefault()
   $.ajax({            
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'insertar.php',
            data :$("#formulario1").serialize(),
            success :  function(data) {                 
                 if(data=="ok"){ alert("comentario enviado")}else{ alert("error al 
                enviar comentario")}
            },error:function(error){
              console.log(error)
           }
         })
  })
}
```

## php

```
//comentario es el atributo name de la etiqueta input del form
if(isset($_POST["comentario"])){
  $comentario =$_POST["comentario"];
  //una vez que tengas el valor en la variable  metes la data a tu query sql
    $sql="insert into comentario("id","comentario") values('$comentario')";
   // luego puedes retornar un mensaje para evaluar en el success del ajax
    // si se executa el query correcto 
    if($slq->execute()){ return "ok"; }else{ return "error";}
}
```