# Evitar que la página se actualice en un formulario

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario en una ventana emergente que usa php para procesar los datos, pero, cuando envío, la página se actualiza y la ventana emergente se cierra, necesito mantener la ventana emergente abierta al enviarla, ¿hay alguna manera de evitar que se actualice en php? o html? Gracias.

PD: cuando uso un `iframe` aparece un gran rectángulo en vez del formulario.

Comment: Podrías usar `jQuery` con `AJAX` para el envió de tu formulario dinámicamente y así evitar que se recargue la página. Pero así sin código y sin ver probado nada, es difícil de ayudar, existe bastante información al respecto, te dejo un enlace quizás te puede ayduar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104074/como-usar-ajax-en-un-formulario/104111#104111

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te refieres al elemento <form>, que cuando haces submit se recarga la página.

Mi consejo es: no uses form. No hay ninguna necesidad, puedes maquetar un formulario, poner un botón y con jQuery y Ajax enviar los datos al PHP, como te sugiere @Diablo en un comentario.

No obstante, si insistes en usar form, puedes evitar que se recargue la página agregando return false en el evento onsubmit:

```
<form onsubmit="tufuncion();return false;">
```

Comment: Consejo: cuando las preguntas les faltan detalles como indica la guía de [ask] es mejor esperar a que el OP la mejore ya que en caso contrario puede quedar cerrada